# Identify added or removed text in HTML files using Perl

Tags: html, perl, diff

My problem boils down to, I have multiple versions of the same HTML page, and I want to know if this page has changed using Perl. These files contain html/javascript and written English. The changes are to be displayed to users in a web interface, as the users decide which pages they want to track for changes. Perl scripts on the server where the website is contained download these pages over time and check them for differences.

So far I can identify *if* the page has changed, but not what was added or removed. This is done via formatting the file into only words on their own lines, and comparing line by line. I know that the change is likely to be written, i.e. a new sentence has been added or removed. I want to be able to pinpoint this change.

I have spent a while today trying to use Text::ParagraphDiff but to no avail. I end up with one long file which repeats the two contents many times but no highlighted changes.

So I thought I would ask if anyone knew of best practices or a preferred way to do this. I am scared that I will have to develop some lengthy algorithm that tracks when the file changes, and when they match up again.

Comment: Are you sure `Text::ParagraphDiff` is the right tool, rather than just `Text::Diff`?  In any case, show the code you are trying to use to identify the changes.

Comment: I will give just Text::Diff a go and post my findings if I get closer/stuck. Thanks

Comment: based on your description of the program to Jim Black below, I think you should probably use a version control system and use Perl to interface to it.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best practice would be to store these files in a source code control system, like git or svn.  That way you have version'ed copies of the file available that can be used to diff (just shell out to it), and to recover anything that may have been lost/overwritten.  Any sort of diff'ing would require that you have the original files.  To determine if a file has changed on my production systems, I use a combination of the files date/time stamps (mtime and ctime both) and the output from a checksum on the files (md5sum -b [file]) these values are taken and saved in a archival database.

Comment: I should have noted that this is for end use in a web application, users log in to track changes to online files. I'll add some more context to the original question to see if that spurs any other suggestions. Perhaps I'll maybe combine the two if I can get some useful text output from the source contorl I can display to users in the web application

Comment: Cool.  You can use, I do, Perl to interface with both the database containing your time/checksum information and with SVN to 'see' the changes made to the files.  I do this as an in-house Tripwire like, file monitoring system, and it has an HTML/Javascript interface for our security folks.

Comment: Sounds very complicated and way out of my depth! I will have to look in to it, thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the [untemplate](https://metacpan.org/module/untemplate) utility at the CPAN. It compares two (or more) structured HTML files by [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath), assuming they were generated using the same template. This is a screenshot of a typical session:

[image: untemplate]